# Cómo puedo solucionar este este error de PHP, estoy tratando de conectarme a mi base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

```
base de datos
create database users; 
use users ;
create table usuarios (email varchar (50), contraseña varchar (50));
select * from usuarios;

   

     $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    
    //Esta condición revisa la conexión 
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Conexion fallida " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Conexion exitosa";
    // Insertar Valores a la tabla de la base de datos 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (email, contraseña) VALUES ('thom.v@some.com', 'hola');";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "Me conecté";
    } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

**A la hora de insertar no me da, ya leí algunas cosas pero no me ayuda,
la conexión está bien. PDTA soy nuevo en esto, si me pueden ayudar lo agradecería
ESTE ES EL ERROR:
Error: INSERT INTO usuarios (email, contraseña) VALUES ('thom.v@some.com', 'hola');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) VALUES ('thom.v@some.com', 'hola')' at line 1
**

Comment: ¿y qué error obtienes?

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO usuarios (email, contraseña) VALUES ('thom.v@some.com', 'hola');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) VALUES ('thom.v@some.com', 'hola')' at line 1

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega en la misma el mensaje de error completo

Comment: Acá explican cómo cambiarle el CHARACTER SET: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html

Creo que el que necesitás es `UTF8`. También podés especificarlo al crear la base de datos, así:
`CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de porque te da ese error desde php, tal vez sea por la version de php que estas usando. Yo estoy usando la version 7.4.20 y probe tu query y me funciona correctamente, me hace el insert en la base de datos.

Pero cuando traté de ejecutar el INSERT directamente en la shell, me da el mismo error que a ti. El problema es por el carácter "ñ" en "contraseña". En vez de "contraseña", pon "contrasena" o clave (eso es cuando creas la tabla). o cualquier palabra que no tenga la letra "ñ".

Al crear tu tabla, evita poner caracteres especiales, tildes y esas cosas.